# What is 'is' keyword in Solidity

Tags: solidity, inheritance

When I read `contract A Is B` can this be read as contract A extends from contract B ?

`Is` is a mechanism for inheriting behavior, this is equivalent to objects inheriting behavior in object oriented languages ?

Searching for `is` on http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=is+&check_keywords=yes&area=default does not yield results.

Where to find list of solidity keywords or is reading doc https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/solidity/develop/solidity.pdf required ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `is` keyword (not "Is") is used for [inheritance](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#inheritance) in Solidity.

The closest thing to a list of keywords in the Solidity docs is the [Cheatsheet](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/cheatsheet.html) which has:

- Global Variables
- Function Visibility Specifiers
- Modifiers
- Reserved Keywords
- Language Grammar

Comment: The link provided in the answer leads to a page which says: "This page does not exist yet."

Comment: @YulePale I have updated the link.

Answer (score 0):

`is` is used to import whole code of a solidity smart contract into another.
in below example `a` smart contract have used `b` smart contract inside it.
e.g. `a` can use any variable or function of `b`.

[image: aakash4dev smart contract 1]

[image: aakash4dev smart contract 2]